# Sencha Touch - how to prevent a datepicker from hiding?

Tags: events, sencha-touch, datepicker, hide

I'm using an Ext.picker.Date and I have some checks I run on the hide event. However, if a certain criteria is met, I want to stop the process and have the date picker not hide.

I've tried using the beforehide event, and running my code there, but that event doesn't seem to fire.

Below is the config for my datepicker. If the condition is true, how can I stop the picker from hiding?

Thanks for any help.

```
var datePicker = new Ext.picker.Date({
        docked: "bottom",
        listeners: {
            beforehide: function() {
                console.log("before hide");
            },
            hide: function() {
                if (1 == 1) {
                    //how do I stop the picker from hiding?
                    Ext.Msg.alert("You cannot select that date.");                        
                }

            }
        },
        slotOrder: ["day", "month", "year"],
        useTitles: false
    });
    this.add(datePicker);
```

Comment: how you are hiding the extjs datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Sencha Touch 2? I'm going to assume so, since you're using Ext.picker.Date.

According to the documentation, the date picker doesn't fire a beforehide event:
[Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date)

What you really want to do here is insert some logic after 'Done' is tapped and before the picker hides itself. The picker calls onDoneButtonTap internally; you can inject your own logic like so:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.widget.DatePicker', {
    extend: 'Ext.picker.Date',
    xtype: 'mypicker',

    onDoneButtonTap: function() {
        if (1 == 1) {
            Ext.Msg.alert("You cannot select that date.");
        } else {
            Ext.picker.Date.prototype.onDoneButtonTap.call(this);
        }
    }
});

this.add({
    xtype     : 'mypicker',
    docked    : "bottom",
    slotOrder : ["day", "month", "year"],
    useTitles : false
});
```

This is assuming that your logic will be able to access what it needs within the scope of the date picker. If this isn't the case, you can pass additional configuration to the date picker when you create it...maybe something like acceptedDateRange {...}

The simplest way could be:

```
var datePicker = new Ext.picker.Date({
    docked: "bottom",
    slotOrder: ["day", "month", "year"],
    useTitles: false,
    onDoneButtonTap: function() {
        if (1 == 1) {
            Ext.Msg.alert("You cannot select that date.");
        } else {
            Ext.picker.Date.prototype.onDoneButtonTap.call(this);
        }
    }
});

this.add(datePicker);
```

I think defining your own class like in the first example is the way to go, especially in situations where you inject logic into existing framework code and when you use the component in more than one place. But the second example will work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It looks good. However, I can't get the onDoneButtonTap event to fire. See here: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#20sPa

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on Sencha Fiddle either. Overwriting onDoneButtonTap has no effect on the resulting datepicker. It works on my local build of 2.0.1 though...